# Convert a Live Windows ISO to a Non-Read Only Boot Image

Tags: windows, boot, iso-image, cd

I have a tiny windows boot ISO whos contents is not like a typical windows or windows CD file layout.

The ISO boots fine in a VM however I obvioustly cannot customize the OS because the ISO is read only.

So, is there a way to both boot the OS and then modify it?

Just extracting the ISO does not work even if it is to a partition that has been correctly configured to boot windows.

The iso contains 3 items, a folder called I386, and two files:
WIN51IS, and WIN51IS.SP2

Here is the contents of the i386 folder: https://pastebin.com/PRcgd6NK

Comment: How was the ISO created? An ISO is just a package file commonly representing an optical disk image. Something on an ISO is read only. Period. If you want something to be modifiable, it will not be an ISO and will not be written to an optical disk.

Comment: @Ramhound I'm not sure if it qualifies as a windows to go application@music2myear
 The ISO was created using barts PE builder, this is a detail I left out because I'll get hated on for using older windows OS's.... , Yes I need something like a USB boot disc or HDD  where I can write to it.

Comment: I am not looking to install win8 or win10.